# Why does `find -size -1G` not find any files?

Tags: find

When I issue:

```
find / \( -type f -size +10M \) -and \( -type f -size -1G \)
```

I don't receive any results; however, when I type:

```
find / \( -type f -size +10M \) -and \( -type f -size -1000M \)
```

it returns a few files.

What's wrong?  Can't I use different unit of measurement in both sides of the operator `-and`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem isn't related to the `-and` operator, but to the unintuitive syntax of the argument of `-size`. The argument is not a maximum size given with a unit, but a maximum number and a unit in which the calculation is performed. The test `-size -1k` does not mean “less than 1kB” but “the number of kB (rounded up) is less than (and not equal to) 1”. Thus, `-size -1k` only matches files of size 0, and likewise for `-size -1M`, `-size -1G`, etc.

To match files that are 2<sup>30</sup> bytes or less, use `-size -2G`, or `-size -1025M`, etc. (observe how `-2G` is not equivalent to `-2048M`). Alternatively, use `! -size +1G` — a size with the `+` modifier means “strictly more than this size”. To match files that are 2<sup>30</sup> -1 bytes or less, use `-size -1073741824c`.

I think the reason why `-size -NUMBERUNIT` is so weird is for historical compatibility with `-size -NUMBER`, which counted blocks; rounding up makes sense since a file occupying e.g. 7.5 blocks is effectively occupying 8 blocks with the last block not filled up. Hence `-size -8` means “occupying 7 blocks or less”. Adding a unit works as if it was making that unit the block size, so `-size -8k` means “occupying 7kB or less”.

(This answer is about GNU find — some other implementations behave differently, and POSIX doesn't standardize units other than blocks and bytes.)

Comment: Evaluating `-size -1M` & `-size -1G` as `0` varies by platform. GNU find does this, BSD find does not. Logically, it's hard to argue that "less than `2^20`" means `0`!?